# pygame.init error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

I was programming a pygame project, I'll show you...

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
pad_width = 1024
pad_height = 512

def runGame():
   global gamepad, clock

crashed = False
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        gamepad.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

    pygame.quit()


def initGame():
    global gamepad, clock

    pygame.init()
    gamepad = pygame.display.set_mode((pad_width, pad_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pyflying')

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    runGame()


initGame()
```

This is the code, now the error....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/dongjune/Desktop/PyCharm/scratch.py", line 36, in <module>
   initGame()
 File "C:/Users/dongjune/Desktop/PyCharm/scratch.py", line 33, in initGame
   runGame()
 File "C:/Users/dongjune/Desktop/PyCharm/scratch.py", line 14, in runGame
   for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

I don't know how to program this.... If you know the error, please answer!!!
And, I'm a newbie to pygame.... ㅠ.ㅠ If you know how to use pygame please tell me! Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong, fix this:

```
def runGame():
    global gamepad, clock

    crashed = False
    while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True

            gamepad.fill(WHITE)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

      # pygame.quit() Remove this line, it shouldn't be in a loop or just break after it's executed
```

Comment: oh, then you have to remove  `pygame.quit()`. It's in wrong place.